# PHP rel=NOFOLLOW

Tags: php, curl

I want to download files, from an website using PHP.

And i want to create an php script to download files without going on their website to download files. I just want to pun their link on my script an download the file automatically.

I try with CURL, but doesn't work.... The link is like this `<a rel="nofollow" href="/download-15866-114621.srt"><b>Download</b></a>`

the code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
  'http://subtitrari.regielive.ro/download-15866-114621.srt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $contents;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't specific enough. What does happen?

Comment: for example: http://subtitrari.regielive.ro/ticking_clock-15866.html, if you enter here you will see a lot o subtitles for this movie, and i want to make a script to download it

Comment: cosy, they do have a referer check. Set the referer header to http://subtitrari.regielive.ro/ticking_clock-15866.html as I say in my post and it should work. This is probably not allowed by them though, so you may very well get banned.

Comment: I doubt it's the referrer (which is always blank in some browser configurations). More likely blocking the user agent (libcurl). And they also have two session ids, `PHPSESSID` and `bbnaut`.

Comment: The file download did not work for me without referers (I usually block them in my browser), but it did work with the refererer. If it stil doesn't work, there is the possibility of changing the useragent and activating cookies in CURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get "download failed!" as content, which means they probably have some sort of download protection. The best thing is probably to ask them what you should do (assuming you have their permission to download the file) or stop trying (assuming you don't).

Eitherway, try setting a referer header with CURLOPT_REFERER. Maybe they check that header to see that no-one is hotlinked to the file.